Render only one card when no promotion is avaiable
I have the following component that is supposed to display a "No Promotions Available" card when the promotions array is either empty or contains invalid promotions. However, I am getting multiple empty cards when the response is an array of empty objects. I want to show only one "No Promotions Available" card if there are no valid promotions.
Here’s my current code:
import React from "react";
import { Card, CardMedia, Typography } from "@mui/material";

const Promotions = ({ promotions, translate, settings }) => {
  return (
    <Card sx={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", backgroundColor: "background.main" }}>
      {promotions.length === 0 || promotions.every((promotion) => !promotion.Id) ? (
        // Render the "No Promotions Available" card
        <Card
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            height: "300px",
            border: "1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2)",
            borderRadius: "12px",
            backgroundColor: "background.paper",
            boxShadow: "0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
          }}
        >
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            color="text.secondary"
            sx={{
              textAlign: "center",
              fontWeight: "bold",
              fontSize: { xs: "1.2rem", md: "1.5rem" },
              marginBottom: "1rem",
            }}
          >
            {translate("promotions.nopromotionabailable")}
          </Typography>
          <Typography
            variant="body1"
            color="text.secondary"
            sx={{
              textAlign: "center",
              fontSize: { xs: "0.9rem", md: "1.2rem" },
            }}
          >
            {translate("promotions.checkbacklater")}
          </Typography>
        </Card>
      ) : (
        // Render promotion cards if valid promotions exist
        promotions
          .filter((promotion) => promotion.Id)
          .map((promotion) => (
            <Card key={promotion.Id} sx={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", backgroundColor: "background.main" }}>
              <CardMedia
                component="img"
                alt={promotion.baslik || "Promotion Image"}
                height="152px"
                image={`${settings?.cdn_url}/${promotion.foto || "default-image.png"}`}
                sx={{
                  borderRadius: { xs: "0px !important", md: "0px !important", lg: ".4895rem .4895rem 0 0" },
                  objectFit: "cover !important",
                }}
              />
            </Card>
          ))
      )}
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Promotions;

Problem Details:
The promotions array is sometimes returned with 8 empty objects ([{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]).
Even with these empty objects, I still see 8 "empty" promotion cards rendered.
I want to display only one "No Promotions Available" card if the promotions array is either empty or contains no valid promotions (i.e., objects without a valid Id).
Expected Behavior: When there are no valid promotions, only one "No Promotions Available" card should be displayed.
What I have tried:
Filtering the promotions array with .filter(promotion => promotion.Id) to exclude invalid promotions.
Using the condition promotions.length === 0 || promotions.every((promotion) => !promotion.Id) to check for empty or invalid data.
Network Response:
The network tab shows true in the response, but I still get empty cards in the UI.
The array contains empty objects, and I am not sure why they are still being rendered.
What I Need Help With:
How can I ensure that only one "No Promotions Available" card is displayed when there are no valid promotions in the array?

Can you clarify what specifically isn't working as expected?  When you debug, which specific operation is failing?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  (Ideally as a React code snippet but even an off-site example would be helpful if only to observe the problem.)

im trying to render only one card written on it no promotion avaiable, but it renders all the cards written on each of them no promotion available @david

When you debug, is this condition true or false?: promotions.length === 0 || promotions.every((promotion) => !promotion.Id)  What data is observed to be in promotions?  Please update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you are trying to describe.

@David i did add the missing informations!

You've edited the question, but the description of debugging details isn't particularly clear.  It's best that we don't have to guess.  Please update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you are trying to describe.  Most of the code shown here is irrelevant.  You appear to be describing a single data structure and a single conditional operation based on that structure.  That can be illustrated with much less code.

@David i added the required info based on the link provided!
